# Change Root DSE in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, rhel6

To start, I am an OpenLDAP newbie. I hope my terminology is correct, but there's no guarantee.

I am trying to migrate our OpenLDAP server to a new box and, in the process, update our LDAP tree to accurately reflect our current organization name. When the original server was set up in 2004, our organization has a different name that has had to persist in our DNS records and other random places. I'm trying to get rid of that legacy name.

I have successfully migrated our original database from the original server to the new server. I am now trying to figure out how to move our Root DSE to the correct root-level DC. An example might help:

**Current Root:** (What it currently is)

```
dc=org-name,dc=dept,dc=university,dc=edu
```

**New Root:** (What it should become)

```
dc=new-org-name,dc=dept,dc=university,dc=edu
```

We use Apache Directory studio to manage our OpenLDAP server. When I tried to [naively] just change the root to the new name, I got this error:

```
-[LDAP: error code 71 - cannot rename between DSAs]
```

**Update:**

The part that I earlier had about neither tree showing up was an SELinux problem. The type was set wrong on the new database, which was causing neither tree to show up.

I am still having the problem of not being able to move between DSAs. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a work-around for this. If I **copy** the records over from the original tree, I am able to do it. Moving does not work, due to the "cannot rename between DSAs" error.

I thought I would post this answer to help anyone having this trouble, but if anyone has the "proper" answer, I would appreciate it!